# Is there any earning limit as a J-1 Intern?

Tags: usa, visa, immigration, j-visa, internship

I'm a French citizen, recently graduated from a French engineering school and actually performing an internship in San Diego.

I received an internship offer for 6 months as a Software Engineer Intern in San Diego in the same company I work for actually. It's gonna be my 3rd internship in the US and I will stay in Canada and France during 90 days between the two internships.

I will be paid $78k/year which, for me, seems as high as a Junior Software Engineer in San Diego.

Is there any earning limit as a J-1 Intern that can trigger more explanation/issues during the visa interview at the embassy?

Comment: Is it a significant increase over the previous internship? On the other hand is it in a different group. As an example, if the first one was with the QA or IT team, I wouldn't be surprised at an increase if the 2nd one was with the development team.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify, putting on hold.